# why my tight loop doesn't take 100% CPU?

Tags: c, linux

I don't know why there is a big different between test1 and test2 in CPU usage. 
'top' report 90% cpu usage when running test1, while 100% when running test2. Buffer size of test1 is only 1KB to fit my L1 cache, so it's doesn't like a cache-miss problem, I attach cachegrind report after each source code, and env is in the end.

It really confused me, any opinion is welcome.

-----test 1-----------

```
const static int BUFFER_LENGTH=1024; 
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
char buff[BUFFER_LENGTH];

for(uint64_t i =0; i < 100000000; ++i)
    buff[(i*1)%BUFFER_LENGTH] = '1';

return 1;
}

==4813== I   refs:      601,353,862
==4813== I1  misses:          1,032
==4813== LLi misses:          1,007
==4813== I1  miss rate:        0.00%
==4813== LLi miss rate:        0.00%
==4813== 
==4813== D   refs:      400,455,090  (300,341,408 rd   + 100,113,682 wr)
==4813== D1  misses:          8,184  (      6,978 rd   +       1,206 wr)
==4813== LLd misses:          4,970  (      4,047 rd   +         923 wr)
==4813== D1  miss rate:         0.0% (        0.0%     +         0.0%  )
==4813== LLd miss rate:         0.0% (        0.0%     +         0.0%  )
==4813== 
==4813== LL refs:             9,216  (      8,010 rd   +       1,206 wr)
==4813== LL misses:           5,977  (      5,054 rd   +         923 wr)
==4813== LL miss rate:          0.0% (        0.0%     +         0.0%  )
```

-----test 2-----------

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
for(uint64_t i = 0, a = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
    a++;
return 1;
}

==22081== I   refs:      401,352,490
==22081== I1  misses:          1,010
==22081== LLi misses:            989
==22081== I1  miss rate:        0.00%
==22081== LLi miss rate:        0.00%
==22081== 
==22081== D   refs:      300,454,488  (300,340,997 rd   + 113,491 wr)
==22081== D1  misses:          8,162  (      6,966 rd   +   1,196 wr)
==22081== LLd misses:          4,965  (      4,043 rd   +     922 wr)
==22081== D1  miss rate:         0.0% (        0.0%     +     1.0%  )
==22081== LLd miss rate:         0.0% (        0.0%     +     0.8%  )
==22081== 
==22081== LL refs:             9,172  (      7,976 rd   +   1,196 wr)
==22081== LL misses:           5,954  (      5,032 rd   +     922 wr)
==22081== LL miss rate:          0.0% (        0.0%     +     0.8%  )
```

---

Test environment:

CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5606  @ 2.13GHz (4 core*2)

MEMORY: 60G

OS: Linux version 2.6.18-164.el5 (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)) #1 SMP Tue Aug 18 15:51:48 EDT 2009

Comment: It *might* be that the first loop does more operations, and therefore have more chances of being preemted.

Comment: Unaligned memory access when using char?

Comment: The second loop does not need to access any memory at all, `a` and `i` can both sit in registers while spinning. The first one needs to fetch and store sometimes, and sometimes has to wait for a cache fill.

Comment: @Atle But does x86 have hw support for unaligned memory access (some instruction may be exceptions) ?

Comment: @tristian, I'm not sure what does it, just a thought that the unaligned access maybe is slower in the hardware, and that the CPU has to wait longer for the writes to complete (therefore less CPU usage). I found this btw.: http://lemire.me/blog/archives/2012/05/31/data-alignment-for-speed-myth-or-reality/

Comment: Did you check the scheduler that your kernel is set to use?

Comment: how did you get the 90% or 100% by top? the program should run quite fast and exit. Are the results stable if you run it multiple times?

Comment: can you provide argument that you use for compilation? It might be useful to look one level deeper and see what asm compilator generate

Comment: Idea: Something along @wildplasser idea.  The `malloc()` does not truly allocate that huge buffer until the various pieces of it start to be used.  During the deferred true memory allocation, the CPU take time to go out to do other things.